# Discord/Python: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Asset") to str

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i was debugging and, i think i found the problem. but i don't understand it

here's the code

```
async def ship(ctx, qim: discord.Member = None):
  #if no one is pinged
  if not qim:
    
    # Error message
    await ctx.send("bu sunucudaki birini etiketleyin!")
  #if someone is pinged continue
  else:
   
   #author and pinged users profile pictures
   pic1 = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
   pic2 = qim.avatar_url
   
   #their usernames without # tag
   name1 = str(ctx.message.author.display_name)
   name2 = str(qim.display_name)
   
   #send the variables, of course for debugging
   await ctx.send(' pic1: ' + pic1 + ' pic2: ' + pic2 + ' name1: ' + name1 + ' name2: ' + name2)
```

that throws this error when somone pinged

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Asset") to str
```

i googled what's asset and found nothing ://

i have no idea why it doesn't work, i copied somone elses homework on this part of code  its weird it doesn't work.

im trying to get their (both pinged user and author of the message) username and save them to variable.

[image: pic1]

console:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Asset") to str
Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Asset") to str
Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Asset") to str
```

and also, whats asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the docs for user.avatar_url [Link to docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=asset#discord.User.avatar_url) it says that the return type is 'asset'. If you wrap the calls in str() then it should convert the url to of type string.

e.g.

```
pic1 = str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
pic2 = str(qim.avatar_url)
```